# Apply all attributes of default product type to custom product type via install script

Tags: product, product-attribute

There is a way to add specific attributes to a Custom product type via install script like this:

```
$fieldList = array(
    'price',
    'special_price',
    'special_from_date',
    'special_to_date',
    'minimal_price',
    'cost',
    'tier_price',
    'weight',
    'tax_class_id'
);

// make these attributes applicable to products of Custom Product type
foreach ($fieldList as $field) {
    $applyTo = explode(',', $installer->getAttribute('catalog_product', $field, 'apply_to'));
    if (!in_array('coreproduct', $applyTo)) {
        $applyTo[] = 'customroduct';
        $installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product', $field, 'apply_to', join(',', $applyTo));
    }
}
```

Is there a way to apply ALL attributes of, let's say, Simple product (with all created and custom attributes and tabs, not known at the moment of extension installation) via install script to Custom product type? My guess would be something with LIKE statement for 'apply_to' field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a attribute to a product type you need to use `apply_to`.

```
// Get the current apply_to settings for your attribute
$applyTo = explode(',', $installer->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $field, 'apply_to'));
// If the attribute is not already assigned to your product type
if (!in_array('your_custom_product_type', $applyTo)) {
    // Update apply_to to include your new type
    $applyTo[] = 'your_custom_product_type';
    $installer->updateAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $field, 'apply_to', implode(',', $applyTo));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

could be like this:

```
//Get the 'Default' attribute set id
$attributeSets = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_attribute_set_api')->items();
foreach ($attributeSets as $set) {
    if ($set['name'] == 'Default') {
        $defaultSetId = $set['set_id'];
        break;
    }
}

//Get the attributes to the 'Default' attribute set
$attributes = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_attribute_api')->items($defaultSetId);
$fieldList = array();
foreach($attributes as $attribute){
    $fieldList[] = $attribute['code'];
}
```