# Remove product attributes for a custom product type

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, magento-2.1.3

I created a new product type, but doesn't need to have all product attributes - like price, stock, weight, etc. How can i remove the attributes only for one product type?

Here is [a solution for Magento 1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17289/apply-all-attributes-of-default-product-type-to-custom-product-type-via-install)(no biggie to adjust it to Magento 2) by updating *apply_to* for the attribute. But that could make a lot of problems later on(for example, if you need to install a third party module which has a new product type and you forgot to add it into *apply_to* list).

My question: It there other way to remove product attributes for a specific product type?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to remove some of the attributes that you want to remove, for example: weight, price, sku and etc.If you go to admin panel -> Stores -> Attributes -> Attribute Set and if you open default attribute set you will see which one can't be removed /they have little red sign/.
You can create attribute set from default attribute set and you can remove all attributes that are unnecessary.

How to do it programatically check on the link below.

https://www.smartiehastheanswer.co.uk/magento2/creating-eav-product-attributes-in-magento2-programmatically.html